# Python Array Slice With Comma?

Tags: python, list, numpy, slice

I was wondering what the use of the comma was when slicing Python arrays - I have an example that appears to work, but the line that looks weird to me is

```
p = 20*numpy.log10(numpy.abs(numpy.fft.rfft(data[:2048, 0])))
```

Now, I know that when slicing an array, the first number is start, the next is end, and the last is step, but what does the comma after the end number designate? Thanks.

Answer (score 72):

It is being used to extract a specific *column* from a 2D array.

So your example would extract column 0 (the first column) from the first 2048 rows (0 to 2047). Note however that this syntax will only work for numpy arrays and not general python lists.

Comment: thanks for specifying **this syntax will only work for numpy arrays and not general python**, I had a bit of headache trying to make it work on vanilla Python.

Comment: I'm confused: how a "syntax stuff" can work *only* with a package?
Shouldn't the "syntax stuff" be accepted *in general* and so in Vanilla, should it?
Is the package numpy modifying the interpreter / compiler?
(I come from Java and C, so in my head the syntax is strongly fixed and unmovable)

Comment: It works with the package because they've implemented the relevant behavior for their `__getitem__` function. Python simply passes in the relevant arguments, but regular 2D lists won't know what to do with it.
See more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165751/what-does-a-colon-and-comma-stand-in-a-python-list

Comment: To be clear, there's no syntactic difference. Python supports using  any object in the brackets, and numpy is choosing to use a tuple.

Comment: @user976850 does Python even have 2D lists?  You can make a list of lists but that's not the same thing.

Answer (score 47):

Empirically - create an array using numpy

```
m = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: (i +1)* 10 + j + 1, (9, 4), dtype=int)
```

which assigns an array like below to `m`

```
array(
      [[11, 12, 13, 14],
       [21, 22, 23, 24],
       [31, 32, 33, 34],
       [41, 42, 43, 44],
       [51, 52, 53, 54],
       [61, 62, 63, 64],
       [71, 72, 73, 74],
       [81, 82, 83, 84],
       [91, 92, 93, 94]])
```

Now for the slice

```
m[:,0]
```

giving us

```
array([11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61, 71, 81, 91])
```

I may have misinterpreted Khan Academy (so take with grain of salt):

> In linear algebra terms, `m[:,n]` is taking the `nth` column vector of
>   the matrix `m`

See Abhranil's note how this specific interpretation only applies to numpy

Comment: This should be top since top link is dead.

Answer (score 16):

It slices with a tuple. What exactly the tuple means depends on the object being sliced. In NumPy arrays, it performs a m-dimensional slice on a n-dimensional array.

```
>>> class C(object):
...   def __getitem__(self, val):
...     print val
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> c[1:2,3:4]
(slice(1, 2, None), slice(3, 4, None))
>>> c[5:6,7]
(slice(5, 6, None), 7)
```

Comment: Okay, so I'm trying to understand - the comma is basically giving you two separate slices? EDIT: But it does this for each individual slice? Like c[5:6, 7] will return the seventh index for each fifth value in the c array (like if the fifth value in the c array was another array or list)?

Comment: Okay, so　if I get this right, a comma will return a column of an array (in its simplest form, a 2D array, for example)?