# What does a colon and comma stand in a python list?

Tags: python, numpy

I met this in a python script `list[:, 1]` and I am trying to figure out the role of the comma.

Comment: That's a numpy syntax. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: specifically, that command is accessing two different dimensions of the data structure (rows and columns)

Comment: This syntax will raise `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple` , so I'm sure the object was not a regular Python list.

Comment: hmm, you ask about lists, but it has the numpy tag on it, and your syntax works only on numpy arrays instead of lists. I assume you do not understand the difference between numpy arrays and the python lists, and thus your question?

Comment: @usethedeathstar Ashwini added the numpy tag on the assumption that this is a numpy array.

Comment: @poke Yes, but than the syntax in the question should be changed as well, since it is not list[:,1] but arr[:,1] since now it is just going to confuse people

Comment: @usethedeathstar In the end, it’s OP asking the question though…

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python's slice notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: You are right, I now realise this is indeed a numpy array, not a list, and thus must be a numpy syntax. Got it, thanks for spending time with me!

Comment: It's still Python syntax, not NumPy syntax. NumPy just supports it.

Answer (score 64):

Generally speaking:

```
foo[somestuff]
```

calls either `__getitem__`, or `__setitem__`.  (there's also `__getslice__` and `__setslice__`, but those are now deprecated, so let's not talk about that).  Now, if `somestuff` has a comma in it, python will pass a `tuple` to the underlying function:

```
foo[1,2]  # passes a tuple
```

If there is a `:`, python will pass a slice:

```
foo[:]  # passes `slice(None, None, None)`
foo[1:2]  # passes `slice(1, 2, None)`
foo[1:2:3]  # passes `slice(1, 2, 3)
foo[1::3]  # passes `slice(1, None, 3)
```

Hopefully you get the idea.  Now if there is a comma and a colon, python will pass a tuple which contains a slice.  in your example:

```
foo[:, 1]  # passes the tuple `(slice(None, None, None), 1)`
```

What the object (`foo`) does with the input is entirely up to the object.

Comment: what a boss explanation :D I've just read PEP8 and I've reached the pet peeves part where it says that in slices, the colon : acts as a binary operator, so I immediately googled more and landed here, now I see how the [] subscription method is creating a slice with colon between numbers when there are multiple objects..

Comment: Would be helpful to add that for a numpy array (which is where most people will encounter this), `foo[:, 1]` will return the column of the 2d array at index 1 (and will throw an exception if foo is not a 2d array).

Answer (score 51):

Lets assume `list` is a 2D (numpy) array as follows:

```
[[ 1, 2, 3],
 [ 4, 5, 6],
 [ 7, 8, 9]]
```

```
list[1,1]  # --> 5
```

It says select the element in position [1,1] (note that indexes start from zero)

```
list[:,1]  # --> [2,5,8] 
list[1][1]  # --> 5
list[:][1]  # --> [4 5 6]
```

See [this](http://scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/array_object.html) and [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) for further examples.

Answer (score 6):

In a sense the comma separates the different dimensions of your array that you are trying to select from.

Lets say I have a 2D array

```
my_array = numpy.array([[1,2,3],
                        [4,5,6],
                        [7,8,9]])
```

I could select rows(0 and 1) and columns(1 and 2) by doing this:

```
#             rows | cols
print(my_array[0:2, 1:3]) # prints [[2 3]
                                    [5 6]]
```

Answer (score 3):

The comma serves to separate the indexes and the colon to get all the elements of a dimension. Let's take a look at an example:

```py
A = np.array([
      [1,2], # --> i0
      [3,4], # --> i1
]) #   | |
   #   v v
   #  j0 j1

A[0,0] # 1

A[:,0] # [1,3]
A[:,1] # [2,4]

A[0,:] # [1,2]
A[1,:] # [3,4]

A[:,:] # [[1,2], [3,4]]
A[:]   # [[1,2], [3,4]]
A      # [[1,2], [3,4]]
```

Given a `numpy` 2D array, `A[i,j]` selects the element of the i-th row and j-th column.

*Note* : `j` can be omitted.

If you use a `:` in either position, it means "**grab all**" from the row/column.

- `A[:,j]` grabs all the **rows**, but just gets the elements of the j-th **column**.

Likewise,

- `A[i,:]` grabs all the **columns**, but just gets the elements of the i-th **row**.

Bonus:

- `A[:,:]` grabs all the **rows** and all the **columns** (equivalent to `A[:]` or plain `A`).