# list of list from text files and accessing index of the lists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have two text files, in each file there are 10 values. Now I want to include these 10 values as two lists in one list and access index of the lists of list. But the problem is I get an error saying, "list indices must be integers, not tuple" . Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

in the first file I have
0.001
0.017
0.07
0.09
0.05
0.02
0.014
0.014
0.021
0.033

In the second file I have

0.001
0.01
0.0788
0.09
0.0599
0.0222
0.014
0.01422
0.0222
0.033

```
import numpy as np

d=[]
one = np.loadtxt('one.txt')
two=np.loadtxt('two.txt')

d.append(one)
d.append(two)


#I get this error "list indices must be integers, not tuple ", when 
# I try to access the index of my lists inside the list

print (d[0,:])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a colon and comma stand in a python list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165751/what-does-a-colon-and-comma-stand-in-a-python-list)

Comment: try `d = np.array([one, two])` lists do not allow multidimensional indexing, but numpy arrays do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start out with numpy, so stick with numpy! You don't want `one` and `two` in a list, you want them as the rows of a 2d numpy array:

```
d = np.array([one, two])

d
# array([[ 0.001  ,  0.017  ,  0.07   ,  0.09   ,  0.05   ,  0.02   ,
#          0.014  ,  0.014  ,  0.021  ,  0.033  ],
#        [ 0.001  ,  0.01   ,  0.0788 ,  0.09   ,  0.0599 ,  0.0222 ,
#          0.014  ,  0.01422,  0.0222 ,  0.033  ]])
type(d)
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
d.shape
# (2, 10)
d[0, :]
# array([ 0.001,  0.017,  0.07 ,  0.09 ,  0.05 ,  0.02 ,  0.014,  0.014,
#         0.021,  0.033])
d[:, 4]
# array([ 0.05  ,  0.0599])
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Paul. Now I understand where I went wrong. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

`d[0,:]` is not a thing. Not sure what you're trying to do here. Try `d[0]`.

Some additional info:

`d` is a 2-dimensional list. (It is a list of lists.) Here's an example to show how to access certain parts:

```
>>> d = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> d[0]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> d[1]
[4, 5, 6]
>>> d[0][2]
3
>>> d[0][1:]
[2, 3]
>>> d[1][:2]
[4, 5]
>>> e = [d[0][1], d[1][1]]
>>> e
[2, 5]
```

Make sense?

Comment: suppose I want to access, the 2nd value of each list, how would I do that?

Comment: `d[0][1]` and `d[1][1]`.