# Error in Python process: <type 'exceptions.IndexError'>: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Tags: python, random-forest

I have to work on someone else's code, who left the company, and I can't figure out what the last line of this is supposed to do ? Any idea ?

```
modele1 = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=96,
                              criterion= 'entropy',
                              random_state=2,
                              n_jobs=-1,
                              min_samples_leaf=100,
                              max_depth=20)  
modele_churn_1=modele1.fit(X_train, Y_churn_1_train)
Y_score_proba_churn_1 = modele_churn_1.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1] # this line throws the following error :
```

> Error in Python process: : index 1 is
>   out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Comment: I think this answer will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972391/python-array-slice-with-comma

Comment: Check modele_churn_1.predict_proba(X_test).shape.

Comment: Thanks ! (For any future viewers : `[:,1]` selects the first two columns, but my NumPy array has only one column, hence the error message)