# NumPy ndarray slicing and indexing using comma

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

What basically the commas do in slicing nd array in NumPy?

E.g. for a 3d array, what do these mean?
`a[1,2::] a[:2,3:] a[1:2,:]`

I means commas in general, how do these thing work while slicing? I know about
`a[start:stop:step]` but having hard time understanding what to commas imply.

Edit: I've read on few websites about slicing using tuple,that is what I don't understand. How does slicing with tuple work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Array Slice With Comma?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972391/python-array-slice-with-comma)

Comment: The comma separates the indices for each dimension.  With a 3d array you may see up to 2 commas (3 indices).  Technically the comma creates a tuple, but you don't usually need to focus on that.  Don't forget to read some basic `numpy` documentation.

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava @hpaulj So it basically comes down to slicing with tuple. How does slicing with tuple work? Is there any general syntax like `a[1,::]` selects first element from dim 0. Something of this sort.

Comment: Could you be more specific - like share a command and write specifically what didn't you understand about the outcome, and what were you expecting. SO isn't really to provide software development training, but rather to solve particular programming (-related) problems.

Comment: Don't you have an interactive python session running with numpy loaded.  It's a lot easier to understand when you can test bits of code.  `arr[ index1, index2, index3]`.  Each `index` can be an integer, a slice, or a list/array.  Each selects something from a different dimension.