# Python syntax question - colon preceding a variable name

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I'm in the process of learning some ML concepts using OpenCV, and I have a piece of python code that I was given to translate into c++.  I have a very basic knowledge of python, and I've run into some syntax that I can't seem to find the meaning for.

I have a variable being passed into a method (whole method not shown) that is coming from the result of `cv2.imread()`, so an image. In c++, it's of type Mat:

```
def preprocess_image(img, side = 96):
    min_side = min(img.shape[0], img.shape[1])
    img = img[:min_side, :min_side * 2]
```

I have a couple questions:

1. What does the syntax ":min_side" do?
2. What is that line doing in terms of the image?

Comment: I've never seen that usage before, but it looks like slice notation.

Comment: This is a slicing syntax that does not work with base python but [does work with numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972391/python-array-slice-with-comma). It is basically a way of slicing a multi-dimensional list.

Comment: To be more specific to my "slice notation" comment above, it is not a : preceding a variable name, but a : separating a start and end index for a list.  When the start index is not explicit, it is the start of list.  By the same reason, a colon after an identifier means end of list.  a colon alone means the entire list.

Comment: this should be familiar to anyone who's ever used slicing in plain python, with numpy, or with opencv. it is explained in all the basic tutorials that cover these uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am assuming the input of the image is a Matrix. In Python the image is generally read as numpy matrix*

**1.What does the syntax ":min_side" do?**

- It *"Slice"* the List/Array or basically in this case, a Matrix.

**2.What is that line doing in terms of the image?**

- It *"crops"* the 2D Array(Basically a Matrix/Image)

A simple example of slicing:

```
x = np.array([[0, 1, 2],[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
print(x)
```

out:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Performing Slicing on this Matrix(Image):

```
x[:2, :3]
```

output after Slicing:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])
```

A good source to read more about it would be straight from the source: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
img = img[:min_side, :min_side * 2]
```

is cropping the image so that the resulting image is `min_side` in height and `min_side * 2` in width. The colon preceding a variable name is python's slicing syntax. Observe:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
length = 4
print(arr[:length])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

`:min_side` is a shorthand for `0:min_side` i.e it produces a slice the object from the start to min_side. For example:

```
 f = [2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
 f[:3]  # returns [2,4,5]
```

`img = img[:min_side, :min_side *2]` produces a crop of the image (which is a numpy array) from `0` to `min_side` along the height and from `0` to `min_side * 2` along the width. Therefore the resulting image would be one of width `min_side * 2`  and height `min_side` .