# Which Python object(s) can be indexed/sliced with multiple entries in square brackets?

Tags: python

I am playing with Python and found a script online which contains a function. I wrote a simple analogous example below:

```
def func(thing):
    test = thing[0,:]
    print(test)
```

I do not know what datatype the variable "thing" is in this case. What kind of Python datatype/object can be called with square brackets like this?

If you run (using my example above) the variable "thing" as an np.array, dict or list, I get the error: "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

Comment: Neither NumPy array nor dict will call them self a list.

Comment: Why was this reopened? I'm not quite sure how this isn't a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216972/what-does-it-mean-if-a-python-object-is-subscriptable-or-not

Comment: @esqew That's not about tuples as indices.

Comment: Apologies if it is poorly posed i just have genuinely never seen something be called with square brackets like this before

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972391/python-array-slice-with-comma...

Comment: @Samwise Right, and the lowest-voted answer there even talks about more than just NumPy (so that's good for this question). I don't think I saw that when I reopened, only saw that other question shown by esqew and disagreed with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not know what datatype the variable "thing" is in this case. What kind of Python datatype/object can be called with square brackets like this?

Any object that has a [`__getitem__` method](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) can be subscripted.

```python
thing[0, :]
```

is simply syntactic sugar for

```python
thing.__getitem__((0, slice(None, None, None)))
```

So, it is up to that object whether it wants to accept one, two, three, four, or however many parameters and whether it wants to accept certain types of parameters.

For example, the following can generate the error message you posted:

```python
class Foo:
  def __getitem__(self, x):
    if not isinstance(x, (int, slice)):
      raise TypeError(f"list indices must be integers or slices, not {type(x)}")

foo = Foo()

foo[0, :]
```

The reason for the somewhat cryptic error is that multiple indices are desugared into a tuple. So, a `__getitem__` which only expects a single parameter will be passed a `tuple` argument.

Comment: many thanks, I know where to look now for more information